# How do I turn off jul log formatting in tomcat 7?

Tags: java, tomcat, logging

I have an app that runs on tomcat. App applies it's own logging format and then tomcat applies it's own on top of that.

Here's my `logging.properties` in application:

```
handlers = org.apache.juli.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = ALL
org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = my_app.

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = ALL
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
```

Log sample:

```
14-Jun-2019 10:55:46.060 INFO [ajp-nio-8009-exec-6] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log D, [2019-06-14T10:55:46.059316 #21616] DEBUG -- : CACHE (0.2ms)  SELECT * FROM users WHERE user.id = 1 ORDER BY user.id ASC FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY  [["id", "1"]]
```

Rails app format:

```
D, [2019-06-14T10:55:46.059316 #21616] DEBUG -- :
```

Tomcat format:

```
14-Jun-2019 10:55:46.060 INFO [ajp-nio-8009-exec-6] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log
```

I have tried setting `formatter` to `org.apache.juli.OneLineFormatter` but it didn't seem to make any difference. I also tried setting the `java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format="%n"` and that didn't make a difference either. Not sure where to go from here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems like I've been setting the wrong thing...

Setting  this 'solved' the issue for me. Still not perfect but it split's the log onto two lines

```
org.apache.juli.FileHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
```